# beacon-chain-1 level=error msg="Beacon node is not respecting the follow distance" prefix=execution

Tags: eth-2.0, beacon-nodes

I am trying to set up and Eth V2 PoS blockchain
However i keep on failing and have in the logs the info :
beacon-chain-1  | time="2024-02-20 09:56:54" level=error msg="Beacon node is not respecting the follow distance" prefix=execution

I can not find where that comes from and how to fix that
Anyone knows what this "distance" represents ?
What should be done to fix that issue

Thanks
Regard